# How to add text labels to a Mapbox GL JS map that has no vector layers?

Tags: labeling, web-mapping, mapbox-gl-js

Using http://bl.ocks.org/danswick/a4de5c170c04fdd38bb4 and https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/cluster/ I made a Mapbox GL JS map.

- It has no vector tiles basemap but raster tiles.
- It has vector data from GeoJSON points that get clustered.

Now the text labels for the clusters are broken:

> evented.js:109 Error: layers.cluster-count.layout.text-field: use of
>   "text-field" requires a style "glyphs" property

I assume that this is because I have no vector style and thus no vector style for "glyphs".

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/4808 says I should add:

```
"glyphs": "http://fonts.openmaptiles.org/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf"
```

which I did. My map definition ends up like this:

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: {
        "version": 8,
        "sources": {
            "simple-tiles": {
                "type": "raster",
                "tiles": [
                    "http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
                    "http://b.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                ],
                "tileSize": 256,
            }
        },
        "glyphs": "http://fonts.openmaptiles.org/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf"
        "layers": [{
            "id": "simple-tiles",
            "type": "raster",
            "source": "simple-tiles",
            "minzoom": 0,
            "maxzoom": 22
        }]
    },
    center: [10.447683, 51.163375],
    zoom: 6
});
```

But all I get are lots of errors

> evented.js:109 Error: Error: Error
>       at Actor.receive (actor.js:81)

How can I get text to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"glyphs": "http://fonts.openmaptiles.org/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf"
```

did not have the font I used. I had to find a different provider. It works just fine with

```
"glyphs": "mapbox://fonts/mapbox/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf"
```